# 3D array representation CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a 3D image. I need to copy that image to cuda's GLOBAL MEMORY by the use of pointers.
Currently I am doing as the following.. In the following implementation the array is a linear 1D array.

```
   float *image = new float[noOfVoxels];
   readImage(image) //one D linear array
   int sizef = noOfVoxels*sizeof(float);
   float *devI;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&devI, sizef);
   cudaMemcpy(devI, image,sizef, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

How can I allocate a 3D array in device memory??

```
    3D array
    float image[][][];
```

Comment: For all sorts of complexity and performance reasons, you really don't want to do that. Indexing into a linear memory allocation (as you have now) is the optimal approach for 3D memory in CUDA.

Comment: @talonmies . I guess you mean "...is NOT the optimal approach for 3D memory in CUDA". Am I right?

Comment: @Mohsen: No you aren't right. What I wrote more than 7 years ago is what I meant. Your second guessing of everything I have posted here since 2011 is getting a bit tiresome

Comment: @talonmies. Sorry for that :-( . As a beginner, I have found some contradictions among books and posts here in SO or other forums. And it's difficult to decide which one to trust. It can be because of typo, my own misunderstanding or etc. Anyway you are a LIFE SAVER here and I don't want to make you angry-;)

Comment: If I was wrong and there was no typo in your comment , then I should figure out how it is optimal when allocation is not performed by cudaMallocPitch or cudaMalloc3D ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you planning to access the data once it's on the GPU?

If you're doing lots of random accesses and would benefit from spatial locality, then you should use cudaMalloc3D and bind it to a 3D texture.

If you're doing predictable, coalesced accesses, then linear memory indexing as you have it now is great.

Comment: I need to access the neighbourhood of the pixels and I need to modify the pixel values.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the memory of your PC is not in 3D. It's just the matter of visualization, so you can convert your 3D image into a single pointer. So why don't you keep the 3D image in the form on a single pointer on Host side.

```
accessing image3D[i][j][z] is same as image3D[ i*cols+j + rows*cols*z];
```

Now feed the singled-pointer image3D to CUDA.

Comment: in case image2D[i][j] it should be as image2D[i+j*cols] so I suggest the overall image3D conversion is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You are best off using [`cudaMallocPitch()`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db.html). It still allocates memory as a single chunk i.e 1d which you must access by converting between 3d subcripts and a 1d index, but the benefit is that it allocates the memory in such a way as to optimize the alignment of the data types.

Alternatively [cudaMalloc3D()](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10.html#g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10) will also return a pointer to pitched device memory

Comment: cudaMallocPitch is for 2D memory. In the performance wise which is better? or in the memory accessing point of view which will be the better way??

Comment: You can still use it for 3D allocation alternatively [`cudaMalloc3D()`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10.html#g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10)  will also return a pointer to pitched device memory (so you still get the benefit of pitched allocation).